# Android activity switch animation background

Tags: android, animation

What I want to achieve is a flip animation when going from activity to activity.

I've seen a recommendation somewhere on SO, that I should use appropriate layout animation in one activity, switch to next one without any animation whatsoever and then execute the second half of the animation in the second activity.

I guess it could work, not tried it yet. But what bothers me is more general aspect - I believe it should be possible to achieve the same effect with activity transition animation, but...

Somewhere (I guess it was SO, but I can't find it now) I've read that during the activity transition animation the background should always be fully covered by the animated activities. I'm not sure why - I can see the background is always black on all my devices, and making it visible during the animation appears to be harmless.

But perhaps it is not guaranteed? Can someone confirm that requirement? Is it officially stated anywhere?